# How can I have an object not react to an hdri in eevee

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, lighting, hdri

I'm making a water animation with objects hovering above it. I have an hdri set up to give the water better color, but my object hovering above the water is too bright. Is there any way to have the objects floating above the water not be lit up by the hdri but still able to be lit by a lamp?

Comment: did you try decreasing the "specular" and increase the "roughness" of that object?

Comment: No, but I'll try that!